# How do I get a list of files that have line count below 18

Tags: shell, count, line, bin

I need to search for files in a directory by month/year and pass them through wc -l or lines and test if [ $lines -le 18 ], or something similar and give me a list of files that match.

In the past I called this with 'file.sh 2020-06' and used something like this to process the files for that month:

find . -name "* $1-*" -exec grep '(1 |2 |3 )' {}

but I now need to test for a line count.

The above -exec worked but when I changed over to passing the file to another exec I get complaints of "too many parameters" because the file name has spaces. I just can't seem to get on track with solving this one.

Any pointers to get me going would be very much appreciated.

Rick

Comment: Are all the files in the same directory?

Comment: @RMobley : Your grep pattern is an extended regexp, so you would have to specify `-E`. Even then, you would grep all lines containing one of the digits `1`, `2` or `3`, even the digit occurs inside the file name.

Comment: @RMobley: An extended regexp to grep for numbers 1-17, would basically be `(1?[0-9]|2[0-7])`, but even then, you would have to specify the option `-w` as well, to avoid a count of i.e. 517 being picked up, and you need to care about filenames which look like those numbers (for instance, a file named `15.txt`).

Comment: Yes all files are in the same directory. I use "find" to assemble the list and pass that through -exec {} to process them separately.

Comment: The file names are long and include spaces, but what I am trying to accomplish is to return the filename of those files that have less than 18 lines of text within.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using `find` and awk. But first some test files (**Notice:** it creates files named `16`, `17`, `18` and `19`):

```
$ for i in 16 17 18 19 ; do seq 1 $i > $i ; done
```

Then:

```
$ find . -name 1\[6789\] -exec awk 'NR==18{exit c=1}END{if(!c) print FILENAME}' {} \;
./16
./17
```

Comment: I will give this some study and see if it gets me started. Thank you for your time.